# How to create /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid

Tags: docker, manjaro, arch

My Manjaro installation did not configure `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` files which are required for rootless containers such as Docker to work.

For e.g. `cat /etc/subuid` returns a file not found error.

I discovered this problem as soon as I installed Docker Desktop and it was taking forever to start.

I followed some advice from [this](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/43#issuecomment-1178652998) page but to no avail because my system did not have the requisite files.

Eventually, I figured out how to create and configure the subuid and subgid files. I have provided the solution below.

Answer (score 3):

To create `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` files, use

```
touch /etc/subuid
touch /etc/subgid
```

To configure the files, I used a wrote a Python program as described [here](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/common/subuid/):

```
f = open("/etc/subuid", "w")
for uid in range(1000, 65536):
    f.write("%d:%d:65536\n" %(uid,uid*65536))
f.close()

f = open("/etc/subgid", "w")
for uid in range(1000, 65536):
    f.write("%d:%d:65536\n" %(uid,uid*65536))
f.close()
```

You can verify the existence and contents of these files with `cat /etc/subuid`

Docker works perfectly now!